# Keep modal open after submitting form (Constant Contact)

Tags: php, ajax, constantcontact

He guys I have a modal.php where I have my form for submitting a new member to constant contact as well as the api key and functions. My issue is that the form action is  so whenever the user submits the modal it goes away. What I want is for the modal to stay open after submission and display a success message for the user. What can I do to fix this? Ajax maybe?

Comment: Yes I think AJAX is your only option